# Android Studio: how to increase set ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT

Tags: warnings, android-studio-3.5

My Android application, being prepared in Android Studio 3.5.3, has a layout with more than 80 different views (and this number will grow). So, the warning `layout has too many views` appears. I'd like to increase variable `ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT` up to 100 (as it is advised in the warning),  but I cannot find where it can be done. Menu `File->Settings->inspections` does provide option `Perfomance->Application size->layout has too many views` describing this warning, so it is possible to suppress it. However, I'd like just to increase `ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT`, not to suppress it at all. I've found an advice to create environment variable `ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT` setting it to 100, but it does not work.

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1):

`ANDROID_LINT_MAX_VIEW_COUNT` is indeed an environment variable. After setting it to a proper value, Android Studio has to be restarted, that I didn't. After restarting, the warning `layout has too many views` disappeared.